# Magento Snippet code in CMS not working with double curly braces {{}}

Tags: javascript, cms

My 3rd party plugin company ask me to Snippet in this code to my CMS page. but Magento did translate something else for the double curly braces.

How can I Snippet in below code to the CMS page?

```
<script id="mediaTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <div class="candid-wall-cell">
        <div class="candid-wall-overlay">
        </div>
        <div class="candid-wall-overlay-text">
            <i class="candid-icon candid-fa-{{> Media.Source.toLowerCase() }}"></i>
            <div>SHOP NOW</div>
        </div>
        <a class='media' data-media-index='{{> Index }}'>
            <img data-original="{{> Media.Images.LowResolution.Url }}" 
                 alt="{{> Title }}" 
                 style="display:inline-block;"
                 class="lazy">
        </a>
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="//api.getcandid.com/scripts/widget.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    candid.wall('#container', { 
        id: '111111111111111111111111111111111111',
        cluster: 'prod-2',
        layoutMode: 'masonry',
        layout: 'standard'
    });
</script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to try to add the script to a separate phtml file and include it in the CMS block. Create a file in your custom theme:

```
app/design/frontend/Custom/default/templates/scripts/myscript.phtml
```

Put your content in the file above (replace Custom with your theme)

On your CMS page, add this tag it include the script on the page

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="scripts/myscript.phtml"}}
```

Good luck

Comment: Hi!, thanks for the reply, is there a folder in between default and template?

Comment: No, that is correct.